# VS 2017 c# forms objects from toolbox no longer creates it's piece of code

Tags: c#, forms

Story:

So I had to format my pc and re installed visual studios, this time the latest 2017 version. I am making a  windows form in c# and in the visual layout, whenever I dropped an item (let's say a richtextbox) from the toolbox, it automatically created it's "code" inside the forms. But this time it didn't. I even tried creating the method void richtextbox1 but it seems that method and the object in the visual UI are not the same thing.

So I ask:

1) how do I "link" a method in the code to it's object in the visual ui.

2) how can enable the setting that everytime i create an object (button, textbox, etc) it automatically gives it a method in the forms code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You haven't provided any information except "The Winforms designer doesn't work". It works for other developers - people would have noticed if it didn't. Without any other information, the only advice one can give is to repair Visual Studio

Comment: BTW what does `created it's "code" inside the forms` mean? You never see the designer.cs file unless you activate the `Display Hidden Files` option.

Comment: What i mean by it's code, it's method in forms.cs, previously everytime I created a button In forms designer, then a new method called void button1_click would be created.

Comment: No, the default event handler appears only if you double-click on the control. It doesn't appear when you drop the control. Event handlers are generated if you double-click on an event in the designer property box. It looks like there's nothing wrong with your VS installation

Comment: Oh... what a silly mistake. Thanks for your help